# How do you find the requested URL with Google App Engine's Python Mail service?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

My Google App Engine app wants to store various incoming emails including who the email was addressed to. I am trying to figure out how to look at the URL the email was posted to so I can find the intended recipient.

app.yaml has:

```
inbound_services:
- mail
handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+ 
  script: handle_incoming_email.py 
  login: admin
```

The Python script has:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    recipient = db.stringProperty()
    subject = db.stringProperty()
    # etc.

class MyMailHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        msg = Message(subject=mail_message.subject, recipient=???)
        msg.put()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([MyMailHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

So if an email is sent to john@myapp.appspot.com, the recipient would be john@myapp.appspot.com. If the email is sent to jane@myapp.appspot.com, the recipient would be jane@myapp.appspot.com, etc.

I know I could sift through the mail_message.to field, but I'd rather look at the actual incoming URL. Seems like it should be straightforward, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The address is in the handler URL, you can look at self.request.path to retrieve it, but really should use mail_message get this value.

Comment: Why look at mail_message? The URL would seem authoritative, since that's the address the email actually arrived at whereas the To field could contain many email addresses including--potentially--more than one with the receiving domain?

Comment: @JerryNeumann are you sure about the to field containing all the recipients of the message and not only the ones who are relevant to the handler?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that last question for sure, but an axiom of email handling is that certain headers aren't changed. IIRC the rules for the "To:" header is that it should reflect all the recipients that the sender intended. There may be other headers added by the MTA that you can use to find out to whom it got actually delivered, but this gets quite murky quickly.

Comment: @Guido With the get method of a handler class, named captured matches in the URL re mapping get sent as arguments to the method. It would seem that the post method would have a similar capability and that then the receive method would as well, but I can't find this documented. If the receive method could be passed re named captures, then this would be easy, as the recipient could just be passed in to receive. But then the WSGI router could not use the mapping() helper method... where can I find the spec for what gets passed and how exactly mapping() works?

Comment: So according to the docs (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail), in the handler, self.request.path is something like /_ah/main/test@example.com.  Surely you can figure out how to get the portion after the last '/' from a string?  (Hint: x.split('/')[-1].)

Answer (score 0):

OK, went to the source to figure out what receive() and mapping() do. I ended up doing what I wanted this way:

```
class MyEmailHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def post(self,recipient):
        # 'recipient' is the captured group from the below webapp2 route
        mail_message = mail.InboundEmailMessage(self.request.body)
        # do stuff with mail_message based on who recipient is

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [(r'/_ah/mail/(.+)@.+\.appspotmail\.com',MyEmailHandler)],
    debug=True)
```

The webapp2 router allows capturing groups, which it sends as arguments to the handler. Here the captured group is the 'recipient' in recipient@myapp.appspotmail.com. But you can't use the mapping() convenience function (which doesn't do anything much in this case anyway) or the receive method in the handler (which really just gets the email message from the request and puts it in the args to receive.)